# Check dig not on my network via command line

Tags: rest, dig

I want to get the results of dig (globally not on my machine) using a cli.

The google toolbox would work but it doesnt seem to have a rest api
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the result by adding @8.8.8.8 at the end